# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-api-client

I am trying to show `google map` with marker on GPS location and showing `latitude` and `longitude` in my app. But when i run my app the below exception is generated in `logcat` and my app crashes

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.accurat.myapp, PID: 12208
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.accurat.myapp/com.example.accurat.myapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2506)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5491)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374    
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
at com.example.accurat.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:112)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6270)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2506) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5491) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
                                                                        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
at com.example.accurat.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:112) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6270) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2395) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2506) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1363) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5491) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
 at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.r.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:115)
 at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:155)
 at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:6074)
 at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:72)
 at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.i.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:62)
 at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
                                                                           at uqw.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms:179)
 at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.newMapFragmentDelegate(:com.google.android.gms:99)
 at uqv.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms:62)
 at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
 at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzc$zza$zza.zzH(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zzIL(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
 at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.onInflate(Fragment.java:1184)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3412)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:378)
```

My `Manifest`

```
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    />


<permission android:name="com.example.accurat.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.accurat.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>


<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"
    />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My **Layout**

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"

    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:text="Get Coordinates"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/latitude"
    android:text="34343"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="26dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/longitude"
    android:text="dsadasd"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/latitude"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/latitude"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="26dp" />

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context="com.example.app.MainActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_below="@+id/longitude"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_save" />

<Button
    android:text="Save Data"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn_save"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" /
```

And finally my **MainActivity**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    _latitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.latitude);
    _longitude = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.longitude);
    btn_get_coordinates = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn_save_data = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

 btn_get_coordinates.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mapFrag.getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);

           /* new TedPermission(MainActivity.this)
                    .setPermissionListener(permissionlistener)
                    .setRationaleMessage("This app needs Permission to find your location")
                    .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    .check();*/

        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mGoogleMap=googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Location Permission already granted
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //Request Location Permission
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

}
 public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
private void checkLocationPermission() {


    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                    .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
        }
    }

}
protected synchronized  void buildGoogleApiClient() {

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    } else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    /*super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);*/
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // location-related task you need to do.
                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    if(mGoogleApiClient == null)
                    {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {
                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                //finish();
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }
        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}

 public void settingRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);    // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);   // 1 second, in milliseconds
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);

    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient,
                    builder.build());

    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {

        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can
                    // initialize location requests here.
                    getLocation();
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
                    // by showing the user a dialog.
                    try {
                        // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                        // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                        status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, 1000);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        // Ignore the error.
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way
                    // to fix the settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    break;
            }
        }

    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1000:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    // All required changes were successfully made
                    getLocation();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Location Service not Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
    }
}


public void getLocation() {

     if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    } else {
        /*Getting the location after aquiring location service*/
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
           // _progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            _latitude.setText("Latitude: " + String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            _longitude.setText("Longitude: " + String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
            Latitude = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
            Longitude = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            DateTime = df.format(c.getTime());
        } else {
            /*if there is no last known location. Which means the device has no data for the loction currently.
            * So we will get the current location.
            * For this we'll implement Location Listener and override onLocationChanged*/
            Log.i("Current Location", "No data for location found");

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();

            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, MainActivity.this);
        }
    }
}
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    double lattitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    mLastLocation = location;

    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }
    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lattitude, longitude);
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("I am here");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
   // _progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    _latitude.setText("Latitude: " + String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
    _longitude.setText("Longitude: " + String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));

    //move map camera
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

}
```

After running my app, it shows me a white screen and then app crashes and the above mention exception shows on `logcat` hitting at the point `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Moreover as seen in the layout i am using a `fragment` and i used it because i have already worked on it.

I have tried to figure out the issue but unable to do it. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: As the error says, you need to add the `meta-data` tag for the API_KEY in your `Android-Manifest.xml`: `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>`

Comment: Oh yes i forgot :/

Comment: What is not clear in the message `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place this tag in your  manifest file

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Give your api key which you got from https://console.developers.google.com/?pli=1